# Nginx does not accept URL as parameter in Sinatra Heroku app

Tags: ruby, heroku, nginx, sinatra

I have a sinatra app with nokogiri gem.

I want to to pass url like `http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-17492445` after `/` for `/:url`

```
http://127.0.0.1:9393/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fnews%2Fworld-us-canada-17492445
```

It works fine on my local development. [image]

I pushed to heroku. Heroku gives 404. Here is the log

[image]

**How to solve the "Not Found" 404 GET request on heroku. Is it because nginx acts differently from my local server(shotgun)?**

Answer (score 0):

I only can suggest this is something wrong with Nginx rewrite rules.
May be it's trying to fild actual file in filesystem or etc. So they can not be changed by Developers.

Try to add additional path in url e.g.

```
http://127.0.0.1:9393/uri/http%3A
```

or even

```
http://127.0.0.1:9393/uri?http%3A...
```

You can easily extract this actual value using Sintra and at the same time such URLs looks more natural with complex URI-encoded values.